# Select2 with AJAX always no result found

Tags: php, json, ajax, select, jquery-select2

Following tutorial [Select2 with AJAX](http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/jquery-select2-ajax-autocomplete-example-with-demo-in-phpexample.html), I am trying retrieve students list with ajax. my input is :

```
<select class="form-control" id="student_id" name="student_id"></select>
```

and the script is :

```
var url = '';
url += "{{ route('api.student_list') }}";
console.log(url); //outputs http://localhost/project-child/public/api/get-students

$( "#student_id" ).select2({        
    placeholder: 'Select an item',
    ajax: {
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      processResults: function (data) {
        return {
          results: data
        };
      },
      cache: true
    }
});
```

The JSON response is similar to

```
[{"id":1,"text":"EJAJUL HAQUE"},{"id":2,"text":"MUSTAK AHMED"},{"id":3,"text":"AZAD HOQUE"},{"id":4,"text":"ANJARUL HAQUE"},{"id":5,"text":"ARIFUL ISLAM"},{"id":6,"text":"SANJITA KHATUN"},{"id":7,"text":"MARINA SULTANA"},{"id":8,"text":"SULTANA BEGUM"},{"id":9,"text":"SABINA KHATUN"},{"id":10,"text":"JENIFA AHMED"},{"id":11,"text":"REJUON AHMED"},{"id":12,"text":"FARITA KHATUN"},{"id":13,"text":"HABIJUL HOQUE"},{"id":14,"text":"JENIFA MUSKAN"},{"id":15,"text":"JOTUFA WAHID"},{"id":16,"text":"MAUSUMI BEGUM"},{"id":17,"text":"ABJARUL RAHMAN"},{"id":18,"text":"JANNATUR ANJU"},{"id":19,"text":"RIYAD "},{"id":20,"text":"RAJIBUL HOQUE"},{"id":21,"text":"UMME SALMA"},{"id":22,"text":"RAFIKUL ISLAM"},{"id":23,"text":"ABJAL HUSSAIN"},{"id":24,"text":"IMAM AHMED"},{"id":25,"text":"NARGIS SULTANA"},{"id":26,"text":"MAFUDA KHATUN"},{"id":27,"text":"SIDDIKUL NAHAR"},{"id":28,"text":"KHALEDA BEGUM"}]
```

But If I search , say EJAJ it says No results found. I am using select version 4.0.3

Answer (score 0):

on processResults  , count data and if its length == 0 then do smt ...

```
processResults: function (data) {
    if(data.length==0){
        getFromGoogle();
    }
    return {
        results: data
    };
},
```

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the whole `processResults` stuff and make your data server turn your JSON array a subarray with key `results`. This way:

```
{"results":[your-JSON-array-above]}
```